# Insert query in SQL Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can i write a insert query inside Function in SQL server 2008. If i tried, im a getting an error of Invalid use of side effecting operator 'INSERT' within the function. Please help me out. But i want it to be a function, not a stored procedure

```
Create function EFT_DL_FUNC_AUDTI_BATCH_START (@i_db_name varchar(20))
returns int as
begin
    insert into table_name(db_name) values (@i_db_name)
    return 0
end
```

Comment: Can you **show us** what you have and explain in more detail what you're trying to do ??

Comment: `Create function EFT_DL_FUNC_AUDTI_BATCH_START
(@i_db_name varchar(20))
returns int
as
begin
insert into table_name(db_name) values (@i_db_name)
return 0
end`

Comment: this is actualy a function which going to insert a row into the table. But im getting the error

Comment: clave: please **do not** put code samples or XML or stuff like that into comments - it's **really hard** to read and understand. Please **update** your original question by **editing** it and provide more information - thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quote from [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3348181/User-Defined-Functions-in-Microsoft-SQL-Server-2000.htm):

> User Defined Functions cannot be used
>   to modify base table information. The
>   DML statements INSERT, UPDATE, and
>   DELETE cannot be used on base tables.

So you can't do an INSERT in a function.

You might want to explain WHY you don't want to use a procedure.