# Error while creating a table-valued function inside SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I'm really a beginner in SQL Server programming. I'm writing a table-valued user defined function but when i execute it I get this errors:

> *Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Select_info_FN, Line 10
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure Select_info_FN, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.*

Here's my code :

```
create function Select_info_FN() returns table
as
begin
    declare @count int
    SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM dbo.info  
    if @count = 0
    begin
        INSERT INTO dbo.info VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)  
    end
    return (SELECT * FROM dbo.info)
end
```

Comment: Well you can't perform an `INSERT` in a function anyway, so even if you correct the other part of the syntax I don't think you're going to get too far...

Comment: You should consider moving this logic to a stored procedure.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5088380/1073631 --  Good luck.

Comment: You can perform an `INSERT` in a table-valued function it it's an insert into the result table, but it's true that you can't perform an insert into a table that exists in the database.

Comment: cehck this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167399/Using-Table-Valued-Functions-in-SQL-Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following.  I don't know what the column names and types are, but you can replace `Column*` with your column schema.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Select_info_FN()
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
    Column1 INT,
    Column2 INT,
    Column3 INT,
    Column4 INT,
    Column5 INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.info) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @result VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @result
                SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5 FROM dbo.info
    END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

However, if your goal is to modify an existing table rather than build a table of data for use in queries, then [Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) is correct that you can't do an insert in a function, and [sgeddes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073631/sgeddes) is correct that you should use a stored procedure.  In that case, try something like the following.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Select_info
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.info) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.info (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
                VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)  
    END
    SELECT * FROM dbo.info
END
GO
```