# SQL function with two statmentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I never have work with T-SQL functions i have this table

```
id   name 
 1   Juan
 2   Maria
 3   Pepita
 4   Pepon
```

i want to insert space in the table to generate e a New ID , something like this

```
 insert into tbfornec (nome) values (' ')
```

and returns the value of this new ID :

```
  select max(idfornec) from tbfornec
```

with this two statments i have try write this:

```
  create function ultimo ()
  returns int @mayor  as

  insert into tbfornec (nome) values (' ')
```

mayor= select max(idfornec) from tbfornec
what i m doing wrong???                                                             k

Comment: you want to return inserted id.

Comment: you can't use functions to insert data. Just read data from a table with a function. For inserting/updating data, use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a procedure and use `scope_identity()` to return the last inserted id:

```
create procedure ultimo (@name varchar(100)) 
as 
begin
  insert into tbfornec values (@name)
  select scope_identity()
end
```

And then to call it:

```
exec ultimo ' ';
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30d9b/2)

BTW -- I don't think you can use `INSERT` statements in user-defined functions.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088252/insert-query-in-sql-function) for addl information.

Comment: thats  work but in this case , to return a value is not better a function???  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying (inserting, updating, deleting, creating, dropping, etc) anything in a database then you should use a stored procedure rather than a function.

A [mathematical function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) is a construct that takes one or more inputs and returns some output. It shouldn't modify any underlying data or structures. An T-SQL function is no different; it is essentially asking the database engine for the answer to a question, rather than requesting it do something.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for me , ist working

```
create procedure ultimo (@name varchar(10)) 
as 
begin
insert into tbfornec (nome) values (@name)
select scope_identity()
end

ultimo ''
```

i dont know that functions dont make insert,delete,update many thanks to you people :)

Comment: So, the solution that worked was @sgeddes's answer?, because they look the same. Except that his answer was using `EXEC`, wich you really should use. There is no real need for you to post the same answer, just comment on that one that it worked (and, though it's not an obligation, you can marked it as accepted)