# SQL server for Function to insert record

Tags: sql-server

How do I insert a record into a table using a function? When I try it provides the following error:

```
Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure insertlocation, Line 11
Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert query in SQL Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088252/insert-query-in-sql-function)

Comment: Can you show your code

Comment: You can't insert using a function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088252/insert-query-in-sql-function. Do you actually mean using a stored procedure? If so, show us the relevant code and we might be able to assist. Without showing the code that generates this error, you have no chance of getting a useful answer.