# Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT'

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE FUNCTION insertrecord(@id int, @location varchar(20)) 

RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT Into [dbo].[Location] (Id,Emploc)values(@id,@location)
    RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

Above code gives following Error

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 15, Procedure insertrecord, Line 11
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.

Comment: Why don't you use an SP instead?

Comment: You cannot do that in a function. You'll need a procedure

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL server for Function to insert record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25503288/sql-server-for-function-to-insert-record)

Comment: @Dhaval Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how are you planning to use this. But you should have a SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertrecord(@id int, @location varchar(20)) 

AS
BEGIN
    INSERT Into [dbo].[Location] (Id,Emploc)values(@id,@location)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```